# Ignore undefined value in object using "for in" loop and IndexOf()

Tags: javascript

So, i need to find every key / value in `searchSpace` object that contains substring in `query` string. For example, key is `3`, `value1: '123abc'`. And it should find every key / value that contains `query = '3'`. 
This is my code:

```
for (let key in searchSpace) {
    if (key.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
    searchSpace[key].value1.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
    searchSpace[key].value2.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        // do something, not the case
    }
}
```

It works. But my object should be able to contain `undefined` or `null` in `value`. Like this:

```
searchSpace['1'] = { value1: 'loremipsum', value2: '12345' };
searchSpace['2'] = { value2: 'ABCD' }; // here, value1 is undefined
searchSpace['3'] = { value1: '123abc', value2: 'ABCD' };
```

How to make my code ignore undefined values in `searchSpace` when i apply `IndeoOf()` or `toLowerCase()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
if (searchSpace[key].value1 && searchSpace[key].value1.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1){ ... }
```

This will first evaluate `searchSpace[key].value1`. If it's null or undefined, it won't try `.toLowerCase()` or `.indexOf()`, so you won't get any errors.

Comment: TY, completely forgot that null and undefined are "falsy" :D

Answer (score 0):

Check if the keys exist first and then if they contain the query

```
for (let key in searchSpace) {
    if (key.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
    (searchSpace[key].value1 && 
     searchSpace[key].value1.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1)) ||
     (searchSpace[key].value2 && 
     searchSpace[key].value2.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1)) {
        // do something, not the case
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer converting objects to array for neat iterations:
With multiple iterations:

```
Object.keys(searchSpace)
  .map(key => searchSpace[key]) // make array of objects
  .filter(({value1, value2}) =>
    value1 && value2 &&
    value1.includes(query) || 
    value2.includes(query)) // leave only needed values
  .forEach(obj => {
    // Do something with results.
  })
```

Or if you need to create new filtered object, we can make it with a single iteration + reduce. Will combine object only with results which consist value1.

```
Object.keys(searchSpace).reduce((total, key) => {
  const obj = searchSpace[key];
  if (!obj.value1) return total.
  total[key] = obj;
  return total;
}, {})
// {1: { value1: 'loremipsum', value2: '12345' }, 2: { value1: '123abc', value2: 'ABCD' }}
```